# Heroku error: filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: django, heroku, gdal

I know this question has been posted many a time, but I am facing this error during Heroku Deployment for my Django Project. I have placed `GDAL-3.1.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` in the root directory of the project. The `.whl` file installs successfully locally, but the mentioned error still persists during deployment.  The **GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH** is set as:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'env/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/gdal301.dll'
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = 'env/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/geos_c.dll'
```

When I try:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following error:

```
Enumerating objects: 14, done.
Counting objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 24.68 MiB | 1.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0       
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.7
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing 
cached dependencies
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.2
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and 
wheel 0.34.2
remote:        ERROR: GDAL-3.1.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is 
not a supported wheel on this platform. #This is the error
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. 
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to desksolutions.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/desksolutions.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/desksolutions.git'
```

My requirements.txt file looks like this. Is there a problem with how gdal file is included?:

```
django-map-widgets==0.3.0
GDAL @ file:///D:/<project_root>/GDAL-3.1.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Python version:

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Please enlighten what could be the problem here as I am stuck for days now.

Comment: Have you figure it out yet? I am having a similar problem but with a different package

Comment: I am having the same problem and I am breaking my head with it. I have a GeoDjango web application and I just can not deploy it. I have tried using the GDAL and GEOS library paths but they also don't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue remained unresolved. I had to shift the map functionality to my mobile application eventually, sorry peeps.